# Solving the system $A\cos x +B\cos y=C$, $A\sin x + B\sin y=D$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, systems-of-equations, recreational-mathematics

It is not a school-related problem, and pretty much the title. I am looking for a way to solve the system of trigonometric equations:
$$
A\cos(x) + B\cos(y) = C \tag{1}
$$
$$
A\sin(x) + B\sin(y) = D \tag{2}
$$

I have already solved the system for the specific case of $A=B$ and am looking to generalize this to $A \neq B$.

For reference, my solution to the specific case $A=B$ is:

$$x = \cos^{-1}(\frac{C}{A} - \cos(\cot^{-1}(\frac{C}{D})-\cos^{-1}(\frac{D}{2A\sin(\cot(\frac{C}{D})})) \tag{3}$$

$$y = \cot(\frac{C}{D}) - \cos^{-1}(\frac{D}{2A\sin(\cot(\frac{C}{D})})) \tag{4}$$

I have been using computer software such as WolframAlpha to solve it, and they do solve it, but I've been unable to come up with a solution by hand after a couple months of working on it pretty regularly.

Can it be solved by hand?

Comment: I apologize that I can't solve this, but I'm just saying you might get a solution faster if you post WolframAlpha's solution.

Comment: You could use the [tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution) (say, $s:=\tan(x/2)$, $t:=\tan(y/2)$) to write $$\cos x = \frac{1-s^2}{1+s^2}\quad \sin x=\frac{2s}{1+s^2}\quad\cos y = \cdots \quad \sin y = \cdots$$ This converts the system into two polynomials in $s$ and $t$ that may be a bit more straightforward to manipulate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move either the terms with $A$ or $B$ to the other side and square:
$$B^2\cos^2y=A^2\cos^2x-2AC\cos x+C^2\\B^2\sin^2y=A^2\sin^2x-2AD\sin x+D^2$$

Now add them together:
$$B^2=A^2+C^2+D^2-2AC\cos x-2AD\sin x$$

Now write $C=R\cos\phi$, $D=R\sin\phi$. So $R^2=C^2+D^2$.
$$B^2-A^2-C^2-D^2=-2A\sqrt{C^2+D^2}(\cos x\cos\phi+\sin x\sin\phi)\\\cos(x-\phi)=\frac{-B^2+A^2+C^2+D^2}{2A\sqrt{C^2+D^2}}$$

We take inverse to get $x$.
Likewise , we can get $y$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I corrected those typos , @JohnOmielan , It should be ok now.

Comment: @RobinSparrow Thanks. Fixed it

Comment: Hi Andrei, I can do it from here, all I'm confused about is the phi symbol. What does it mean?

Comment: I've wrote $C$ and $D$ as components of a vector of length $\sqrt{C^2+D^2}$ at an angle $\phi$ with $C$. This is the transformation to polar coordinates. $\tan\phi=(R\sin\phi)/(R\cos\phi)=D/C$

Comment: Thanks to you, I've solved the system! Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. Make sure you recover the previous result in the case $A=B$. Also, edit your question to have the parenthesis match. You have more open parenthesis than closed ones)

Answer (score 2):

**Final edit: general solution and constraints**

This answer started off as a one-liner for a special case (see rollbacks if you like), but given how long you've worked on the problem (and now me too!) here is rewrite with a general geometric solution, which also shows where @Andrei's solution comes from.

I'm going to treat $A,B,C,D$ as positive, though you could reframe things to accommodate negative values. I also presume $C \leq A+B$ otherwise the first equation cannot be true, and for geometric simplicity that $A,B \leq C$ so that we are not dealing with negative distances at any point. If we fix $A,B$ with $C$ some permissible value of $A,B \leq C \leq A+B$ then we have zero, one, or two solutions as the diagrams below indicate.

**Case $A+B < \sqrt{C^2+D^2}$**

No solution

[image]

**Case $A+B = \sqrt{C^2+D^2}$**

One solution, $x=y= \arctan{\frac{D}{C}}$

[image]

**Case $A+B > \sqrt{C^2+D^2}$**

Two, one, or zero solutions per diagrams below

[image]

[image]

[image]

In this regime, the solutions form a kite in which the diagonal $R= \sqrt{C^2+D^2}$, at an angle $\phi= \arctan{\frac{D}{C}}$, bisects the angle between solutions as $\delta$.

[image]

Since we have $A,B,R$ we can use the Law of Cosines to determine $\delta$:

$$B^2=A^2+R^2-2AR \cos{\delta}$$

And our solutions are $x=\phi \pm \delta$.

With a bit of rearrangement you'll find this coincides with @Andrei's answer. The virtue of this approach is it show you why the suggestions for half-angle formulas, or framing the problem symmetrically, work: it's because of the symmetry of the kite.

Comment: Nice thinking , though it will restrict the Cases to $A\sin(x)=B\sin(y)$ which might not give all Solutions to Original Cases. Instead , we can make a rectangle of Size $C \times D$ & fit the 2 triangles inside it , to get all Solutions to Original Cases.

Comment: @Prem yes, was mostly trying to show that the problem can be reframed to yield quick, simple solutions, but added diagrams for what you mention too, unless you want to make an answer with them yourself.

Comment: I like these updates , though your earlier https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JnHvm.png was useful too

Comment: @Prem lol I try to avoid serial edits like this, but I went ahead and completed the proof for the other case and added back the alternate figures, thanks for the nudges.